# ¿Close a modal of an ANGULAR 5 form?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Well I want that when the button is clicked the modal closes

[image]

main.component.ts 
here you could do something too

```
crear(form){


this._servicio.creararchivos(this.formulario).subscribe(data =>{

this.conseguir();
form.reset();

this._routes.navigate(['/main']);


}, error =>{
console.log('error al crear el archivo');

}  
);
```

my html I think here is the problem would need a function for the button to do the click I have tried with Bostrap dissmiss but I do not send the data just closes me

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
 aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
 <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Subir Archivos</h5>
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-
 label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">

<form (ngSubmit)="crear(a)" #a="ngForm" class="">

<div class="form-group">
<label for="user_id">User_id</label>
     <!--<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" 
 *ngFor="let 
   datos of archivo">-->

   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_id" 
   [(ngModel)]="formulario.user_id">
 <!-- </select> -->

 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="titulos">Titulo</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="titulo" 
 [(ngModel)]="formulario.titulo">
</div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="descripcion">Descripcion</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descripcion" 
 [(ngModel)]="formulario.descripcion">
 </div>


 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="imagen">Imagen</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="imagen" 
 [(ngModel)]="formulario.imagen">
 </div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >SUBIR</button> //this <---

 </form>

  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `@ViewChild` to refer your button in your component :

1. Add a reference to the btn `#btnClose`

   ```
   <button #btnClose type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
   ```
2. Create a `@ViewChild` in your component code

   ```
   @ViewChild('btnClose') btnClose : ElementRef
   ```
3. In the submit function, `click` the btn programtically

   ```
   crear(){
   ...
       this.btnClose.nativeElement.click();
   ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the reference to bootstrap modal. like #exampleModals

   `<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" #exampleModals>`
2. create ViewChild in component.

   `@ViewChild('exampleModals')  exampleModals: ElementRef ;`
3. on clear method `crear(a)` hide the modal.

   `crear(a) {
       this.exampleModals.hide();
       }`